# Firebase 3 - Best methods for password reset

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to create a discussion about the best way to handle a situation such as when you can have users that login with Gmail, Facebook or simple email and yet they have a password change.

Should we allow a password change outside of the simple email authentication?

I think this is why we have fetchProvidersForEmail() method in Firebase 3. It creates a problem when a password is changed when a user's initial provider was based on Facebook authentication.

The Firebase 3.x documentation is a bit nebulous in terms of best practices.